# DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint. SQL issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Delete_AssemblyPartListByProjectId]
    (@ProjectId INT,
     @UserId INT = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE AssemblyPartList 
    SET ParentSequence = NULL 
    WHERE ProjectID = @ProjectId

    DELETE FROM AssemblyPartList 
    WHERE ProjectID = @ProjectId
END
```

I get this error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure dbo.usp_Delete_AssemblyPartListByProjectId, Line 12
> The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.AssemblyPartList_dbo.AssemblyPartList_AssemblyPartList2_AssemblyPartListID". The conflict occurred in database "db-uat-emd-01", table "dbo.AssemblyPartList", column 'ParentSequence'.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AssemblyPartList] 
(
    [AssemblyPartListID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PartID]             BIGINT NOT NULL,
    [PartNO]             NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [OriginalQty]        DECIMAL(18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [AdjustedQty]        DECIMAL(18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [IndentureLevel]     INT NOT NULL,
    [ParentAssemblyID]   BIGINT NOT NULL,
    [Notes]              NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [Cost]               DECIMAL(18, 2) 
         CONSTRAINT [DF__AssemblyPa__Cost__780AAFAB] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [ParentAssemblyAssetItemID] INT
         CONSTRAINT [DF__AssemblyP__Paren__79F2F81D] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectID]          INT 
         CONSTRAINT [DF__AssemblyP__Proje__2018A105] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [ParentSequence]     INT NULL,
    [Description]        NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
    [AssetWBSID]         INT             
         CONSTRAINT [DF__AssemblyP__Asset__1407CFDB] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [AssetItem]          NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AssemblyPartList] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AssemblyPartListID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AssemblyPartList_dbo.AssemblyPartList_AssemblyPartList2_AssemblyPartListID]
        FOREIGN KEY ([ParentSequence]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AssemblyPartList] ([AssemblyPartListID])
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ParentSequence]
ON [dbo].[AssemblyPartList]([ParentSequence] ASC) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80);
```

I can't delete the rows using the stored procedure to delete project data from table. Unsure why as it is null but still has a reference error. The stored procedure used in application to clear data from generated table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have a self-referencing foreign key, which is preventing you deleting this row because there are child rows dependent on it. The `UPDATE` statement isn't helping as that will only affect the parent rows, it's the dependent rows you need to worry about.

You can use a recursive CTE to find all rows (and recursively all child rows) to delete. As long as you delete them all at once then the server will ensure they all get deleted in the right order.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Delete_AssemblyPartListByProjectId
  @ProjectId INT,
  @UserId INT = NULL
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT apl.AssemblyPartListID
    FROM AssemblyPartList apl
    WHERE apl.ProjectID = @ProjectId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT apl.AssemblyPartListID
    FROM cte
    JOIN AssemblyPartList apl ON apl.ParentSequence = cte.AssemblyPartListID
)
DELETE apl
FROM AssemblyPartList apl
JOIN cte ON cte.AssemblyPartList = apl.AssemblyPartList;
```

Do **NOT** use `READ UNCOMMITTED`. It has serious data integrity implications, and should not be used except in specific debugging circumstances.